# TensorFlow Model Server GPU Build - cudnn path

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to build the TensorFlow model server from the source on a RedHat machine. I do not have sudo privileges, and the cudnn is not in the default directory. Is there a way to specify cudnn path when building it?

```
Cuda Configuration Error: Failed to run find_cuda_config.py: Could not find any cudnn.h matching version '10.0' in any subdirectory:
        ''
        'include'
        'include/cuda'
        'include/*-linux-gnu'
        'extras/CUPTI/include'
        'include/cuda/CUPTI'
of:
        '/lib'
        '/lib64'
        '/opt/beegfs/lib'
        '/usr'
        '/usr/lib64/atlas'
        '/usr/lib64/dyninst'
        '/usr/lib64/mysql'
        '/usr/lib64/tcl8.5'
        '/usr/local/cuda'
        '/usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib'
        '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib'
        '/usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib'
        '/usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib'
```

Comment: What version are you trying to build? You should be able to export CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH=<...> prior to running bazel.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I am trying to build the master branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the solution in this (Answer) Section even though it is present in the Comments Section, for the benefit of the community.

We need to specify the CUDNN path using the below command before running **`Bazel`**,

**`export CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH=<...>`**